# How can I complete this REST implementation?

Tags: c#, .net

MyService calls a REST uri using HttpClient.GetAsync(). I'm calling the service method from the Main method of a console app within the same solution but the following result is returned:

```
Id = 3, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

What do I need to do to complete this REST implementation?

MyService:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Services
{
    public class MyService
    {
        private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
        public void GetData()
        {
            var result = await Client.GetAsync("https://www.test.com/users");
        }
    }
}
```

Service call from Console Main():

```
var result = new MyService().GetData();
```

*UPDATE*

Ok I updated my method implementation to look like this:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetData()
    {
        var result = await Client.GetAsync("https://www.test.com/users");
        return result;
    }
```

However, this still returns the same value that I included in my original post.  What am I missing here?

Comment: refactor GetData to return async Task.

Comment: @mason How is OP using HttpClient wrong?  You are _supposed_ to use a private static instance.  Why introduce a seperate library/dependency for a simple GET request?

Comment: If you're going to use await in a method, your method must be marked as async. And if your method is marked as async, it should almost always return either a Task or a Task<T>. By the way, I don't recommend using HttpClient directly. Instead, have a look at Flurl or RestSharp.

Comment: @maccettura They're not necessarily doing it wrong, I misread. I read too fast and thought they were instantiating an instance each time instead of static. However, you should have an HttpClient *per domain*. So if there's another service that hits the same domain, or this service hits other domains, that can be an issue. HttpClient makes things much harder than they have to be. Switching to Flurl or RestSharp keeps you from falling in those pits, has a nicer syntax, and as a bonus can do JSON conversion for you.

Comment: @maccettura Another example where HttpClient is problematic is that it doesn't respond to DNS changes. So let's say you've got a static HttpClient in your service, then the server that it calls out to changes IP addresses (perhaps it's a 3rd party, or perhaps your IT department is changing that DNS record to point to a different internal server). Now your service will stop working, because it hasn't picked up on the new address. The only way to fix it is to restart the service. And that's troublesome, you likely won't know what the cause of your service failing was in the first place.

Comment: @maccettura Sorry to spam you, but here's some good [further reading](http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html). It's kind of fascinating how bafflingly bad this issue is and so few of us are aware of it. A lot of people know to make it static, but they don't know about using one per-domain or how to handle the DNS changes.

Comment: Your original code wouldn't even have compiled so I don't know what you mean by "getting same result". You need to look at the values retueprned by your method calls.

Answer (score -2):

You didn't returned anything from method

```
public async Task GetData()
        {
            return await Client.GetAsync("https://www.test.com/users");
        }
```

return your result from method.

Comment: You can't just return the result. That still won't compile.

Comment: Definitely. You need to change return type too.

Comment: It still wouldn't compile. Have you used `await` before?

Comment: I updated answer. Please have a look. Hope it will help.

Comment: No, still won’t compile. If you’re returning something, you need to set the return type to a Task<T> when it’s async. Stop guessing, take the time to validate that the solution you’re providing is correct.